# I get sanity login error in Vs code and I can't solve it how can I solve it?

Tags: next.js, sanity

I want to install sanity in my next js project, although I have a sanity account, I get a login error after selecting the login type. No method works. How can I solve this error?

Error:

Waiting for browser login to complete... Press Ctrl + C to cancelError: spawn UNKNOWN
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:421:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:761:9)
at baseOpen (C:\Users\meteh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\67a0730928194b24\node_modules@sanity\cli\lib_chunks\cli-PoML_Ct2.js:13444:248) {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'spawn'
}
Unhandled rejection: Error: spawn UNKNOWN

I've searched in the Sanity documentation how to solve this error, I've asked other people but I still can't solve it

Comment: what's your node version? ```node -v```

Comment: node version : v20.10.0

Comment: Try
 remove ```node_modules``` 
then ```npm cache clean -f``` then ```npm install```

Comment: I did, but it's still the same. I deleted the project folder and reinstalled it but it still gives error.

Comment: can you provide a reproduction repo on github?

Comment: Is it okay if I share the link here?